# How do I solve a second order differential equation in R?

Tags: python, r, ode, differential-equations

I am learning ***R*** to solve a second order differential equation(probably using deSolve package). Which I have written in python by writing it as two first order differential equations and is given below

```
import  numpy  as np
import  matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
from  scipy.integrate  import  odeint

def  fun(X, t):
    y , dy , z = X
    M = np.sqrt (1./3. * (1/2. * dy **2 + 1./2.  * y **2))
    dz = (M*z) # dz/dt
    ddy =  -3.* M * dy -  y # ddy/dt

    return [dy ,ddy ,dz]

y0 = 1

dy0 =  -0.1

z0 = 1.

X0 = [y0, dy0, z0]

M0 = np.sqrt (1./3. * (1./2. *  dy0 **2. + 1./2.*  y0 **2)) 

t = np.linspace(0., 100., 10001.) # time spacing

sol = odeint(fun, X0, t)

y = sol[:, 0]

dy = sol[:, 1]

z = sol[:, 2]

M = np.sqrt (1./3. * (1./2. *  dy**2. + 1./2.*  y **2)) 

#Graph plotting
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, y)
plt.plot(t, z)
plt.plot(t, M)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

***Python*** solve this problem easily, however for another similar but complicated problem python shows error. I have also tried ode(vode/bdf) in python but the problem is still there. Now, I would like to check how ***R*** work with the problem. So, I will be much obliged if someone please provide me an example(basically a code translation!) of how to solve this problem in ***R*** so that I can try the other one in ***R*** and also learn some ***R***(I know that this may not be the ideal way to learn a language).

I understand that this question may have little constructive value, but I am just a novice in ***R***, so please bear with me!

Comment: [This paper](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Soetaert~et~al.pdf) gives a good introduction on how to use `deSolve` in `R` with a minimal example about half way through. However I'd suggest you think about why Python shows an error and why you think using `R` will solve your problem.

Comment: I am currently trying to understand why python is showing the error, if I don't find an answer I will ask for help in stackoverflow. However, searching for help, I came across this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973036/odd-scipy-ode-integration-error
And tried to implement ode(vode/bdf) but the problem persists. So now trying R

Comment: I think it will be hard for anyone to help you further without information about the error you have. The post you have linked suggests using `scipy.integrate.ode` to specify whether to use stiff or non-stiff methods. I guess you've done this?

Comment: Yes, I have implemented `scipy.integrate.ode` . For the stiff problem in my case, I first tried the `vode/bdf` and then eventually exhausted all the possible combinations and different orders!  But, the problem is still there.

Comment: I think @MichaelBird is right: translating this into R probably won't solve the problem. I'd venture that both R and Python probably ultimately rely on the same old school ODE code that has just been repackaged.

Comment: Yeah, I would be very happy if both of them have the same problem. Then, I will try to reformulate the problem (In fact, I am trying to check the physics of the issue). But, at least I would like to check it with `R` as I have already done with `Mathematica` and `Matlab`. But, learning to code in `R` from scratch is now a problem for me, hence I asked for help.

Comment: You're on the right track. If "this works but another similar but complicated problem python shows error", you have to show us the problem that *fails* (and, ideally, the error; the error alone *might* give someone a hint). Is it the same problem as in the linked question?

Comment: FYI: In addition to the paper suggested above, they also wrote an accompanying [book](https://www.amazon.ca/Practical-Guide-Ecological-Modelling-Simulation/dp/1402086237) that is helpful for learning modelling with R.

Comment: @BenBolker, I am investigating the reason of the error in python. As this equation came in study of physics, I am trying to check my physics. If all fails, I will ask for help here. Now, searching in stack I came across the linked problem and the sentence there "This also uses lsoda, but seems to be going off without a hitch" gave me motivation to check with `R`

Comment: @Lyngbakr thanks for the reference, I will try to get the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a translation of the Python code to R

```
library(deSolve)

deriv <- function(t, state, parameters){
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)),{

    M <- sqrt(1/3 * (1/2 * dy^2 + 1/2 * y^2))
    dz <- M*z # dz/dt
    ddy <-  -3* M * dy -  y # ddy/dt

    list(c(dy, ddy, dz))

  })
}

state <- c(y = 1,
           dy = -0.1,
           z = 1)

times <- seq(0, 100, length.out = 10001)

sol <- ode(func = deriv, y = state, times = times, parms = NULL)

y <- sol[, "y"]

dy <- sol[, "dy"]

z <- sol[, "z"]

M <- sqrt(1/3 * (1/2 *  dy^2 + 1/2*  y^2)) 

plot(times, z, col = "red", ylim = c(-1, 18), type = "l")
lines(times, y, col = "blue")
lines(times, M, col = "green")
grid()
```

There is a faster way to directly calculate `M` in **R** with this code:

```
library(deSolve)

deriv <- function(t, state, parameters){
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)),{

    M <- sqrt(1/3 * (1/2 * dy^2 + 1/2 * y^2))
    dz <- M*z # dz/dt
    ddy <-  -3* M * dy -  y # ddy/dt

    list(c(dy, ddy, dz), M = M)

  })
}

state <- c(y = 1,
           dy = -0.1,
       z = 1)

times <- seq(0, 100, length.out = 10001)

sol <- ode(func = deriv, y = state, times = times, parms = NULL)

## save to file

write.csv2(sol,file = "path_to_folder/R_ODE.csv")

## plot

matplot(sol[,"time"], sol[,c("y", "z", "M")], type = "l")
grid()
```

[image]