# Solving Non Autonomous System of ODEs

Tags: r, modeling, ode, differential-equations

I am working on a project and need to solve a system of non autonomous ODEs (nonlinear). How can I do this in the programming language R? Is there a specific package I could use? Can someone help me out with any instructions or references? I tried googling but did not find anything too helpful.

Thank you so much! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! This site is for specific questions about programming, and questions asking for recommendations for packages or tutorials are considered off topic. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: look at `deSolve`: examples [here](https://kingaa.github.io/thid/odes/ODEs_in_R.pdf)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I solve a second order differential equation in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074599/how-do-i-solve-a-second-order-differential-equation-in-r)