# How to solve a 9-equations system of non linear DE with python?

Tags: python, physics, ode

I'm desperately trying to solve (and display the graph) a system made of nine nonlinear differential equations which model the path of a boomerang. The system is the following:

[image]

All the letters on the left side are variables, the others are either constants or known functions depending on v_G and w_z

I have tried with `scipy.odeint` with no conclusive results (I had [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973036/odd-scipy-ode-integration-error) but the workaround did not work.)

I begin to think that the problem is linked with the fact that these equations are nonlinear or that the function in denominator might cause a singularity that the `scipy` solver is simply unable to handle. However, I am not familiar with that sort of mathematical knowledge.
What possibilities python-wise do I have to solve this set of equations?

EDIT : Sorry if I was not clear enough. Since it models the path of a boomerang, my goal is not to solve analytically this system (ie I don't care about the mathematical expression of each function), but rather to get the values of each function for a specific time range (say, from t1 = 0s to t2 = 15s with an interval of 0.01s between each value) in order to display the graph of each function and the graph of the center of mass of the boomerang (X,Y,Z are its coordinates).

Here is the code I tried :

```
import scipy.integrate as spi
import numpy as np

#Constants

I3 = 10**-3
lamb = 1
L = 5*10**-1
mu = I3
m = 0.1
Cz = 0.5
rho = 1.2
S = 0.03*0.4
Kz = 1/2*rho*S*Cz
g = 9.81

#Initial conditions

omega0 = 20*np.pi
V0 = 25
Psi0 = 0
theta0 = np.pi/2
phi0 = 0
psi0 = -np.pi/9
X0 = 0
Y0 = 0
Z0 = 1.8

INPUT = (omega0, V0, Psi0, theta0, phi0, psi0, X0, Y0, Z0) #initial conditions 


def diff_eqs(t, INP):  
    '''The main set of equations'''

    Y=np.zeros((9))

    Y[0] = (1/I3) * (Kz*L*(INP[1]**2+(L*INP[0])**2))
    Y[1] = -(lamb/m)*INP[1]
    Y[2] = -(1/(m * INP[1])) * ( Kz*L*(INP[1]**2+(L*INP[0])**2) + m*g) + (mu/I3)/INP[0]
    Y[3] = (1/(I3*INP[0]))*(-mu*INP[0]*np.sin(INP[6]))
    Y[4] = (1/(I3*INP[0]*np.sin(INP[3]))) * (mu*INP[0]*np.cos(INP[5]))
    Y[5] = -np.cos(INP[3])*Y[4]
    Y[6] = INP[1]*(-np.cos(INP[5])*np.cos(INP[4]) + np.sin(INP[5])*np.sin(INP[4])*np.cos(INP[3]))
    Y[7] = INP[1]*(-np.cos(INP[5])*np.sin(INP[4]) - np.sin(INP[5])*np.cos(INP[4])*np.cos(INP[3]))
    Y[8] = INP[1]*(-np.sin(INP[5])*np.sin(INP[3]))


    return Y   # For odeint



t_start = 0.0
t_end = 20
t_step = 0.01
t_range = np.arange(t_start, t_end, t_step)

RES = spi.odeint(diff_eqs, INPUT, t_range)
```

However, I keep getting the same problem as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973036/odd-scipy-ode-integration-error) and especially the error message :

```
Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type)
```

I am not quite sure what it means but it looks like the solver have troubles solving the system. In any case, when I try to display the 3D path thanks to the XYZ coordinates, I just get 3 or 4 points where there should be something like 2000.

So my questions are : - Am I doing something wrong in my code ?
- If not, is there an other maybe more sophisticated tool to solve this sytem ?
- If not, is it even possible to get what I want from this system of ODEs ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to provide an [mcve], i.e., in particular initial conditions and parameters? As it stands, the only way to answer your question is to guess these. Moreover, are you actually close to a singularity? Finally note that SciPy alone comes with two other interfaces for ODEs.

Comment: This looks like the problem might be the dreaded gimbal lock, the polar coordinates at the poles are singular, they change disproportionally to position changes near the poles. One work-around is to use quaterntions instead or not to use polar coordinates at all.

Comment: @LutzL: When correcting for the order of arguments (via the `tfirst` argument of `odeint`), I get the same problem. I also fail to integrate this with every integrator in Python. When looking at it in detail, it’s ω_z going of into the thousands very quickly with increasing speed, which seems unphysical to me. This may be a gimbal lock (θ is almost at π/2), but it could also be an error in the differential equations.

Comment: I deleted the previous comment as this was a division problem. Activating python3 division I also see this error.

Comment: Could you add some more details on how the equations are connected to the code, especially the first and third equation? It could be helpful to get a little more on the physical interpretation of the variables.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues:

- if I copy the **code**, it does not run
- the  workaround you mention does not work with odeint, the given
  solution uses ode
- The scipy reference for odeint says:"For new code, use
  scipy.integrate.solve_ivp to solve a differential equation."
- the call *RES = spi.odeint(diff_eqs, INPUT, t_range)* should be
  consistent to the function head *def diff_eqs(t, INP)* . Mind the
  order: *RES = spi.odeint(diff_eqs,t_range, INPUT)*

There are some issues about to **mathematical** formulas too:

- have a look at the 3rd formula on your picture. It has no tendency term, it starts with a zero - what does that mean ?
- it's hard to check wether you have translated the formula correctly into code since the code does not follow the formulas strictly.

Below I tried a solution with *scipy solve_ivp*. In case A I'm able to run a pendulum, but in case B no meaningful solution for the boomerang can be found. So check the maths, I guess some error in the mathematical expressions.

For the **graphics** use pandas to plot all variables together (see code below).

```
import scipy.integrate as spi
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def diff_eqs_boomerang(t,Y):   
    INP = Y
    dY = np.zeros((9))
    dY[0] = (1/I3) * (Kz*L*(INP[1]**2+(L*INP[0])**2))
    dY[1] = -(lamb/m)*INP[1]
    dY[2] = -(1/(m * INP[1])) * ( Kz*L*(INP[1]**2+(L*INP[0])**2) + m*g) + (mu/I3)/INP[0]
    dY[3] = (1/(I3*INP[0]))*(-mu*INP[0]*np.sin(INP[6]))
    dY[4] = (1/(I3*INP[0]*np.sin(INP[3]))) * (mu*INP[0]*np.cos(INP[5]))
    dY[5] = -np.cos(INP[3])*INP[4]
    dY[6] = INP[1]*(-np.cos(INP[5])*np.cos(INP[4]) + np.sin(INP[5])*np.sin(INP[4])*np.cos(INP[3]))
    dY[7] = INP[1]*(-np.cos(INP[5])*np.sin(INP[4]) - np.sin(INP[5])*np.cos(INP[4])*np.cos(INP[3]))
    dY[8] = INP[1]*(-np.sin(INP[5])*np.sin(INP[3]))
    return dY   

def diff_eqs_pendulum(t,Y): 
    dY = np.zeros((3))
    dY[0] =  Y[1]
    dY[1] = -Y[0]
    dY[2] =  Y[0]*Y[1]
    return dY

t_start, t_end = 0.0, 12.0

case = 'A'

if case == 'A':         # pendulum
    Y = np.array([0.1, 1.0, 0.0]); 
    Yres = spi.solve_ivp(diff_eqs_pendulum, [t_start, t_end], Y, method='RK45', max_step=0.01)

if case == 'B':          # boomerang
    Y = np.array([omega0, V0, Psi0, theta0, phi0, psi0, X0, Y0, Z0])
    print('Y initial:'); print(Y); print()
    Yres = spi.solve_ivp(diff_eqs_boomerang, [t_start, t_end], Y, method='RK45', max_step=0.01)

#---- graphics ---------------------
yy = pd.DataFrame(Yres.y).T
tt = np.linspace(t_start,t_end,yy.shape[0])
with plt.style.context('fivethirtyeight'): 
    plt.figure(1, figsize=(20,5))
    plt.plot(tt,yy,lw=8, alpha=0.5);
    plt.grid(axis='y')
    for j in range(3):
        plt.fill_between(tt,yy[j],0, alpha=0.2, label='y['+str(j)+']')
    plt.legend(prop={'size':20})
```

[image]

Comment: @Antoine : I'm glad to hear how you proceed with the boomerang

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the issue for a moment, I was busy with others assignment. I will look into this and will share the results if I can get this to work. 
And you are right, the maths are wrong (and the implementation in Python even wronger). I will restart from scratch and see if I can get satisfactory results.